# Why are beta blockers a banned substance?

Tags: doping

I was reading some of the bodybuilding organisations list of banned substances and it mentions beta blockers. One of the types of beta blockers Atenenol is a medication that has been prescribed to me by a doctor for perfectly legitimate reasons.

I never imagined that some random blood pressure medicine could get me banned out of a sport. I must admit that reading this was rather disappointing.

I have never done any type of drugs and the only medication I have ever taken was the ones prescribed to me by doctors. I'm left wondering why blood pressure medicine is the first banned substance bodybuilding organisations mentions. There seems to me to be many more egregious drugs.

Comment: Will try and dig into this more later, but a number of drugs are banned because they act as "masking agents" which hide the signatures of actual performance enhancing drugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta blockers reduce [sympathetic effects](https://www.acc.org/Latest-in-Cardiology/Articles/2021/11/16/19/11/Cardiovascular-Medications-on-the-World-Anti-Doping-List#:%7E:text=Beta%20blockers%20reduce%20sympathetic%20effects,%2C%20golf%2C%20shooting%20and%20fishing.), which can have an impact on competitive sports that are reliant on stability of extremeties (by reducing the symptoms of anxiety, such as tremors).

> Beta Blockers
>
> > Beta blockers reduce sympathetic effects, such as increases in heart rate and blood pressure, which often are heightened during athletic competition. WADA explicitly prohibits beta blockers in sports that are reliant on stability of the extremities, such as archery, racing, billiards, darts, golf, shooting and fishing.

While beta blockers used to be banned only during competition, that [was changed in 2023](https://www.usada.org/athlete-advisory/key-changes-2023-prohibited-list/) to at all times in some sports.

I do note, however, that WADA at least does not ban beta blockers in weightlifting and similar sports, according to [the list](https://www.wada-ama.org/en/prohibited-list?filters%5Bprohibited_type%5D%5B%5D=%22Beta-blocker%22):

> - Archery (WA)*
> - Automobile (FIA)
> - Billiards (all disciplines) (WCBS)
> - Darts (WDF)
> - Golf (IGF)
> - Mini-Golf (WMF)
> - Shooting (ISSF, IPC)*
> - Skiing/Snowboarding (FIS) in ski jumping, freestyle aerials/halfpipe and snowboard halfpipe/big air
> - Underwater sports (CMAS)* in all subdisciplines of freediving, spearfishing and target shooting

Comment: Wait, there is a group regulating doping in mini-golf?